How does the Chinese Embassy have detailed records of its citizens residing in northern Shan State, Myanmar?
I read on irrawaddy.com (mirror):

The Chinese Embassy has detailed records of its citizens residing in northern Shan State, he said.

How does the Chinese Embassy have detailed records of its citizens residing in northern Shan State, Myanmar?

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about expatriation

Chinese is a surveillance state, and so is Myanmar. How's it even a question?

@littleadv  Chinese citizens residing in northern Shan State, Myanmar are expats. Some of these expats would like to know how is that possible. E.g., must they register? 100% on topic. Your view on these countries is irrelevant to determine whether the question is on-topic.

Redddit user Buergermeeschter gave the following answer:

Those who are long-term Shan/Mandalay-region residents will make use of the consular dept. in MDY and thus make their records known. For example, Chinese guys who have married a Shan/Wa/Kokang girl. Or who need documents to invest in mining operations. So the records mainly come from those who have provided them to the embassy/consulate to begin with
(there are also... MNDAA/MNTJP officials who are married to Chinese nationals who are employees at the consulate in MDY... and this obviously creates a situation where the Kokang administration is able to... access certain records. but this is probably an entirely different discussion)

